# Coin flips and binomial distribution

Tags: probability

Consider a sequence of $100$ flips of a fair coin. Let $X$ denote the number of pairs of heads in this sequence, i.e. $HH$. Notice that we also consider the pair $X_{100}X_1$ (like a cyclic ordering). Am I correct that $X$ is described by a binomial distribution since the trials are independent and fixed, only two outcomes, ...?

Comment: Do pairs overlap? Like $THHHHT$ would be three pairs.

Comment: @Snoop Yes, a pair is defined as $X_iX_{i+1}$ where both are heads

Comment: Let's work with small numbers first. You throw N=3 coins. The possibilities are
{TTT,HTT,THT,TTH,HHT,THH,HTH,HHH}
The corresponding number of HH pairs with also the circular hypothesis are
{0,0,0,0,1,1,1,3}
So P(0)=1/2,P(1)=3/8,P(2)=0,P(3)=1/8. Doesn't look very binomial.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's binomial because each flip is not the same Bernoulli.

I am here defining trial $n$ to be the pair of flips $n$ and $n+1$, (mod $100$ since if $n= 100$, then you loop back to $1$). Success here means "pair of heads" and failure is "anything else."

Suppose flip $n$ is heads. Then the probability of trial $n$ being a success is $1/2$, since it's all dependent on flip $n+1$. However, if flip $n$ is tails, then the probability of trial $n$ being a success is $0$, since flip $n+1$ cannot make a pair of heads.

For this reason, since the trials don't have a fixed probability of success, I think it's not binomial.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $N = 2.$ Then  $P(HH) = 1/4$

Suppose $N = 3$. Then of the $8$ possibilities, $HHH$ has $3$ pairs, $3$ options have $1$ pair, and $4$ options have no pairs.

Suppose $N = 4$. Then of the $16$ possibilities, $1$ has $4$ pairs, $4$ have $2$ pairs, of the $6$ ways to have $2H2T$, $4$ of them have $1$ pair, and none of the ways with $1$ or $0$ heads have any pairs.

This is not binomial.

Comment: How could I modify this problem to being able to apply Chernoff's inequality?